# How do I place UIImageView between cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have created two prototype cells in my `UITableViewController`, and want to place a `UIImageView` object between them. Simply put, I want a cell on top, then an `Image View`, and then a cell at the bottom.

When I try to place the `UIImageView` in storyboard, I can't place it between the two prototype cells.

How do I go about doing this? I am using swift.

Comment: you cant do that. Simply put the imageview in a cell between two cells

Comment: @Mr.T Would I need to add a custom class to it?

Comment: It is your choice. For simply making every every second cell contains an image, doesnt need a custom class!!!

Comment: @Mr.T Okay, thanks! You can add this as an answer if you want, and I would tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add an imageview between the two cells. But you can add the imageview to the cell between two cells. You can customise the imageview cell height,so that it looks like a customised separator.

Or You can also add the imageview to the very bottom of the tablecell, so that it looks like the imageview between the two cells.